# Problem with query and php variable

Tags: php

Hello I have the following php script

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$sql = "select uid from #__zcalendar_events where article_id = " . $article->id;
$db->setQuery($sql);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
    if(count($results)) {
        foreach($results as $r => $value) {
            $sql = "select catid from #__zcalendar_event_categories where uid = " . $r->field1;
        print_r($results);
        print_r($sql);
```

My problem start in this line:

```
$sql = "select catid from #__zcalendar_event_categories where uid = " . $r->field1;
```

the `. $r->field1;` does not add the value to the string `$sql`.

But if I `print_r($results);` I get the this information:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [uid] => 2011-08-22-12-24-35-62-0@cttcorp.hexasystems.com ) )
```

And I need just this: `2011-08-22-12-24-35-62-0@cttcorp.hexasystems.com`

and `. $r->field1;` have to had this information but it's always empty.

Can someone please help me to solve this problem, because I have the information. But never works.

Comment: Are you meaning to use $value->field1, not $r perhaps?

Comment: Also, you have 7 questions and you've not accepted any of them. You might want to work on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreach is usually like this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $element)
```

Are you sure you want to be using  the `$r` not the `$value`?

Comment: +1 - and the other mistake was to use `$value->field1` but there is no `field1` instead he should write `$value->uid`

Comment: Yes I want the uid, but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: So does $value->uid give you 2011-08-22-12-24-35-62-0@cttcorp.hexasystems.com?

Comment: You're very welcome. Please mark an answer as correct or up if it helped you out.

Comment: Hey I have another proble, the value that I get goes to this link
$link = "option=com_zcalendar&vmode=e&view=".$eventview."event&format=html&tmode=m&eid=$eid";
in the .$eventview. but I get this empty but it have the value. Can you help me with this, too???

Comment: Is hard to see posted in the comment section - can you post it properly, with all the surrounding code too?